# Momentum Conservation in Lighthill Acoustic Analogy

Tags: acoustics, aerodynamics, navier-stokes

I have a question of Lighthill Acoustic Analogy. In his paper, the approximate equation of momentum is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\rho v_i) + a_0^2 \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_i} = 0 $$
Would you tell me what is the second term? Why it is related to momentum?

Comment: I don't know Lighthill acoustic analogy exactly, but it quite looks like continuity equation.

Comment: Continuity equation has a cumulative term of density. This equation has a cumulative term of momentum. So I think this is equation of momentum.

Comment: [Engineering Acoustics/Analogies in aeroacoustics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Analogies_in_aeroacoustics)

Comment: @Farcher Thank you so much. The website seems help my study.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

The second term is just the gradient of the pressure, or net external force on a fluid particle.

**Justification:**

If you linearize the equation of state and assume adiabatic (or isothermal) behavior, you arrive at the equation
$$ P = P(\rho) \approx P_0 + \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\rho}\right)_0(\rho-\rho_0), $$
where $P$ is the pressure, $\rho$ is the mass density, and the subscript $0$ denotes the quantity evaluated at equilibrium.  If we write
$$ \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial\rho}\right)_0 \equiv a_0^2, $$
assume the equilibrium state is not a function of position, and take the gradient of the pressure, we obtain
$$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} \approx a_0^2\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x_i}. $$
Thus, under these assumptions (homogeneity, adiabatic, and small acoustic perturbations of the fluid fields) the equation of momentum may be equivalently written as
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho v_i \right) + \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} = 0 \hspace{5mm} \Leftrightarrow \hspace{5mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho v_i \right) + a_0^2\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_i} = 0. $$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I could understand the transformation. In order to understand the second equation, I read this website. [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Speed_of_sound). However I could not get why sound wave speed is $$U=c_0-u'$$ Would you explain it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what that website is doing.  The equations of continuity and momentum they pose make no sense to me at all.  Furthermore, the equation you give, $U=c_0-u'$, is not correct if $U$ is the mean particle velocity and $u'$ is the velocity perturbation.  If you include nonlinear effects, you could write $c=c_0+u'$, where $c$ is the actual sound speed and $c_0$ is the linear sound speed.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense for me. Thank you so much!